# Loading values from config.xml to jelly file on Page Load

Tags: jenkins, config, jenkins-plugins

I have a custom form in my Application and I would like to load values to its fields.

For this purpose I have a class that extends from ItemListener and have overriden the onUpdated method to read the updated config file and set values to the text box fields by creating an Action object,adding that action object to the project  and saving the project. For some reason this does not work. The code snippet is below!

**Action Class:**

```
public class MyAction<T extends AbstractItem> implements Action {
final private T item;
public String gitRepo;
public String gitBranch;
public String mavenGoals;
public String mavenPOM;
public String eMailRecipient;

@DataBoundConstructor
public MyAction(T item, String gitRepo, String gitBranch, String mavenGoals, String mavenPOM, String eMailRecipient) {
    this.item = item;
    this.gitRepo = gitRepo;
    this.gitBranch = gitBranch;
    this.mavenGoals = mavenGoals;
    this.mavenPOM = mavenPOM;
    this.eMailRecipient = eMailRecipient;
}
//Getter methods follow...
```

**ItemListener Class:**

```
@Extension
public class MyActionListener extends ItemListener{

@Override
public void onUpdated(Item item){
    if(item instanceof AbstractItem)
    {
        for(Action action : Jenkins.getInstance().getActions())
            if(action.getClass()==MyAction.class)
            {
                AbstractProject proj=(AbstractProject) item;
                XmlFile projConfig=proj.getConfigFile();
                String config=projConfig.toString();
                String gitRepo=config.substring(config.indexOf("<url>")+5, config.indexOf("</url>"));
                String branch=config.substring(config.indexOf("<name>")+6,config.indexOf("</name>"));
                String mavengoals=config.substring(config.indexOf("<target>")+8,config.indexOf("<target>"));
                String mavenPom=config.substring(config.indexOf("<pom>")+5,config.indexOf("</pom>"));
                String eMailReceipient=config.substring(config.indexOf("<recipientList>")+15,config.indexOf("<recipientList>"));
                Action newAction=new MyAction((AbstractItem) item,gitRepo,branch,mavengoals,mavenPom,eMailReceipient);
                proj.addAction(newAction);
            try {
                proj.save();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MyActionListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            }
    }
}
```

}

**Jelly form:**

```
<f:form method="post" name="config" action="configSubmit">
    <f:block>
    <f:section title="${%Job Configuration}">
        <f:entry title="${%Job name}">
        <f:textbox id="name" name="name" default="${it.ItemName}"/>
        </f:entry>
   </f:section>
   <f:section title="${%Source Code Management}">
       <f:entry title="${%Git Repo}">
           <f:textbox id="repo" name="repo" default="git@github.scm.corp.mycompany.com:{Enter your git repo here}" value="${it.GitRepo}"/>
       </f:entry>
       <f:entry title="${%Branch}">
           <f:textbox id="branch" name="branch" default="master" value="${it.GitBranch}"/>
       </f:entry>
   </f:section>
       <f:section title="${%Maven Targets}">
       <f:entry title="${%Goals}">
           <f:textbox id="goals" name="goals" default="-U clean install" value="${it.MavenGoals}"/>
       </f:entry>
       <f:entry title="${%POM}">
           <f:textbox id="pom" name="pom" default="pom.xml" value="${it.MavenPOM}"/>
       </f:entry>
   </f:section>
   <f:section title="${%E-Mail Notification}">
       <f:entry title="${%Recipient}">
           <f:textbox id="emailrecipient" name="emailrecipient" default="QE DL For Notifying" value="${it.eMailRecipient}"/>
       </f:entry>
   </f:section>
   <f:section title="${%Assembler Postbuild}">
        <f:entry title="${%Assembler Target POM.xml{relative path}}">
            <f:textbox id="assemblerpom" name="assemblerpom"/>
        </f:entry>
   </f:section>
   </f:block>
    <f:bottomButtonBar>
    <f:submit value="${%Save}" />

  </f:bottomButtonBar>
</f:form>
```

Comment: Is this a question? What do you want to know?